# autorefresh async datagrid using WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf, silverlight

I have a asp.net datagrid and it displays a data coming from WCF web service. My requirement is that I want data grid to keep on refreshing based on rapidly changing WCF data. I can use a timer and set an interval to refresh but is there a way for refresh to happen based on change of data only which can be triggered from WCF message. For example, Trading dashboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a duplex WCF service to push stuff down to your web server. [You can read about them here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx). From there, you will have to use something like long polling or web sockets to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..! I will find more on that.